# need help to add another OS at my custom grub2 (fallout4 theme)? is Kali Linux and I don't use Kali's theme

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.10, kali

**I tried to update my grub, but it doesn't work**

```
sudo update-grub
```

I have ubuntu 19.10 and windows 10 installed and they show in grub' However, I installed *kali Linux* in sda7, but I don't know how to put it.

may someone help me, thank you

Comment: Only one OS can own the MBR (first-512-bytes-of-disk) which is usually the last installed OS.  `update-grub` will only work IF run on the OS that owns the MBR, otherwise you need to `grub-install` first (which will take ownership of the MBR).

Comment: If Windows & Ubuntu are UEFI, did you also install Kali in UEFI boot mode? Otherwise grub will never boot it. Grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode  as Ubuntu is installed UEFI or BIOS.